# Inconsistent behavior between Java and Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm using a shared library in both `Android` and `Java` and have found this inconsistency on its behavior.

The library depends on `org.json.JSONObject`. Which is in a jar contained on the library itself, but it seems that somehow Android overrides that jar with its own implementation of JSON.

When I do:

```
    Double a = 0.1;
    JSONObject b = new JSONObject();
    b.put("Hola", a);
    flockSONversionString = b.getString("Hola");
```

In `Android`, it runs with no problems, but in `Java`, it throws an exception because 0.1 is not a String. The second behavior is the one that I expected from the beginning.

when I do

```
    Object aObj = b.get("Hola");
    if(aObj instanceof Float){
        System.out.println("Hola is Float");
    } else if (aObj instanceof Long){
        System.out.println("Hola is Long");
    } else if (aObj instanceof Double){
        System.out.println("Hola is Double");
    } else if (aObj instanceof String){
        System.out.println("Hola is String");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hola has unknown type");
    }
```

Both in `Android` and `Java` I get `Hola is Double`.

The curious thing is that, if you go to the source code of `org.json.JSONObject` the `getString()` method is declared as follows:

```
public String getString(String key) throws JSONException {
    Object object = get(key);
    if (object instanceof String) {
        return (String)object;
    }
    throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + quote(key) +
        "] not a string.");
}
```

Which seems totally as the expected behavior because it's checking if the `Object` is a `String` and throwing an exception if it isn't.

Any idea why would this be happening?

Thank you!

(I can't change the dependency on `org.json.JSONObject` since this would break the compatibility between `Android` and `Java` )

Comment: Thanks all for the advice. At the end, to get a consisten behavior between platforms, instead of getString(), I'm using get()  and checking for it to be a string manually. It seems that, when in Android, you can't call an external instance of org.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the same jar in both projects?

Android's `org.json.JSONObject.toString(String)` is different:

```
/**
 * Returns the value mapped by {@code name} if it exists, coercing it if
 * necessary, or throws if no such mapping exists.
 *
 * @throws JSONException if no such mapping exists.
 */
public String getString(String name) throws JSONException {
    Object object = get(name);
    String result = JSON.toString(object);
    if (result == null) {
        throw JSON.typeMismatch(name, object, "String");
    }
    return result;
}
```

`JSON.toString(Object)`:

```
static String toString(Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        return (String) value;
    } else if (value != null) {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In your case this would not throw an exception on Android.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the jar is contained in the lib folder of my library, so it's supposed to use it no mather where the library it's being called. The problem is that it seems that somehow Android is overriding that library and using it's own implementation of JSON on it...

Answer (score 0):

```
String aString = Double.toString(aDouble);
```

passastring instead of (a);

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, android source for `getString`

```
 /**
 * Returns the value mapped by {@code name} if it exists, coercing it if
 * necessary, or throws if no such mapping exists.
 *
 * @throws JSONException if no such mapping exists.
 */
public String getString(String name) throws JSONException {
    Object object = get(name);
    String result = JSON.toString(object);
    if (result == null) {
        throw JSON.typeMismatch(name, object, "String");
    }
    return result;
}
```

The important line here is `String result = JSON.toString(object);`. Above it, will call `get` (method explained bellow), and it will convert your double to a string by calling `JSON.toString` (you can go further in sources to check it out)

Now for second part of code, when you do `get(KEY)` it will return an object (bellow the code for it) and you will have a double, since that's what you put.

```
 /**
 * Returns the value mapped by {@code name}, or throws if no such mapping exists.
 *
 * @throws JSONException if no such mapping exists.
 */
public Object get(String name) throws JSONException {
    Object result = nameValuePairs.get(name);
    if (result == null) {
        throw new JSONException("No value for " + name);
    }
    return result;
}
```

As a conclusion, these are the methods android uses for JSONObject, I have checked the java sources and it seems that the methods `getString` and `get` have different logic. I assume that you compile once for android (with android sdk) and once for java project and thus you have this results.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, It seems that the behavior of JSON on Android is the one from the Android code you pasted and the behavior on Java is the one on the library I'm using. The problem is that my library is supposed to be calling the JSON jar inside it. It seems that, when Android pulls the library, it calls Android's JSON jar, the one that casts Double (or any otrher type) to String. Is there a way to override this behavior?

Comment: I assume that your library has the same package as android's JSON package (that's the only thing that i can think of ). If possible try to change the package name of the library. Or make sure that you are using the correct imports.